# how to make a js script available globally?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find any question similar  to what I'm looking for, that is why I'm asking here.

The problem is very simple, since I do not have so much experience with js. I would like to solve this simple problem.

**I have the follow JS Code**

```
function valida()
{
    if (document.getElementById('contrato').value=='0')
    {
        alert('O contrato do cliente deve ser selecionado!');
        document.getElementById('contrato').focus();
        return false
    }
    if (document.getElementById('problema').value=='0')
    {
        alert('A tipo da ocorrência deve ser selecionado!');
        document.getElementById('problema').focus();
        return false
    }
    if (document.getElementById('descricao').value=='')
    {
        alert('A descrição do problema deve ser preenchido!');
        document.getElementById('descricao').focus();
        return false
    }
}

function mostra()
{
    if (document.getElementById("sumula").style.display != "none")
    {
        document.getElementById("sumula").style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("sumula").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Actually the above piece of code is in my HTML interface and work properly. But now I need to restructure my interface and separate it in 7 other small interfaces (No problem at this point).
Then I will have 7 distinct new interfaces, and I do not want to repeat the JS code as above, then I had created a new js file called `protocol.js` and I will include the `protocol.js` in all my 7 new interfaces.

I'm including like this ->

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/protocol.js">
```

but it is not working. Just this not work. 
When I back the whole code in my HTML it works fine, I had try absolute path, relative path and nothing.

What could it be?
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/protocol.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep.  You have to close the script tag with a separate close tag, even when you use the src attribute.

Comment: auto close -> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/protocol.js" /> should work?

Comment: @FernandoCosta you **cannot** auto close a script tag.

Comment: I try to use exactly as the answer posted  above, but it not help. Still not works.

Comment: @Neal Thanks for the warning. Plus one!

Comment: @FernandoCosta read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work for more info on the script close tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. The file is not accessible (Use the correct chmod)

   Try to call it like http://DOMAIN/scripts/protocol.js
2. The tag is not correct. It's not closed. Try

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/protocol.js"></script>`

Comment: I did as you mentioned and still not working. 1 - It is a windows server no chmod option.! I try absolute and relative path, also the full path accessible by url and nothing. 2 - I correct the tag and still not working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put a link on here? It might help people spot the error

Comment: You can also have a look to the Javascript console. In Firefox you have a console in the add-ons Firebug and Web Developer. I also created a minimal example: http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/stackoverflow/8053588/ - you could copy and try it.